# QNAPのObject Storage Serverを使っていますがコンテナの中身(リスト)が見れない

Tags: amazon-s3

QNAPでObject Storage Server(OSS)を使っています。

他のLinuxでs3cmdをインストールしてアクセスしてみました。
QNAPでは
sample01
sample02
のコンテナがあります。両方ともPublicにしています。

```
# s3cmd ls
2009-02-03 16:45  s3://sample01
2009-02-03 16:45  s3://sample02
```

でコンテナの一覧は確認できますが、

```
# s3cmd ls s3://sample01
ERROR: Access to bucket 'sample01' was denied
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied): Access denied
```

でsample01の中身を見ることができません。アクセス拒否がされています。

```
# s3cmd info s3://sample01
ERROR: Access to bucket 'sample01' was denied
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied): Access denied
```

でも同様です。

このAccess controlはどこで設定するものなのでしょうか？もしくはアクセスする手段が違うのでしょうか？
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: `s3cmd --configure` でアクセスキーは設定済みですか？

Comment: はい。設定しております。そのおかげで# s3cmd lsは実行できていると思っています。

Comment: 了解です。チュートリアルによると「OSS ユーザーがアクセスするストレージアカウント (共有フォルダー) を明示的に許可する必要があります。」「OSS でストレージアカウントのアクセス許可リストに追加しない限り、該当するストレージアカウントにはアクセスできません。」とありますが、この辺も設定されてますか？

Comment: あと「ストレージアカウント」にもアクセス権の設定がありますが、OSSユーザを追加してみると何か変化はありますか？

Comment: 「共有フォルダ」の共有フォルダー権限の編集にて該当フォルダの全てのユーザを追加して読み取り/書き込み権限を付与。ゲストのアクセス権までフルアクセス。NFSホストのアクセスも許可するIPアドレスで読み取り/書き込み権限を付与。Microsoftネットワークホストのアクセスでも許可ネットワークを追加。「OSS」のStorage Accountで全てのユーザを追加完了しています。しかし、s3cmd ls s3://sample01がaccess denyになります。

Comment: 「共有フォルダ」のアクセス権限ではなくて「ストレージアカウント」の方のアクセス権限があるようですが、そちらは許可されてますか？ ご参考）[QTS で S3 と OpenStack に対応するオブジェクトストレージサービスをホストする :: バックアップ ::NAS :: QNAP](https://www.qnap.com/ja-jp/tutorial/con_show.php?op=showone&cid=136)